# What proportion of UK statutory instruments are passed using the negative resolution procedure?

Tags: united-kingdom, legislature

I know that most EU directives are implemented via Statutory Instruments passed via the negative resolution procedure, but is this procedure commonly used for law with a UK origin?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about government statistics, not the law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What proportion of UK statutory instruments are passed using the negative resolution procedure?

On average, about 90% ([source](https://www.parliament.uk/documents/commons-information-office/l07.pdf), [source](https://researchbriefings.parliament.uk/ResearchBriefing/Summary/SN06509))

For session-by-session numbers, the [Sessional Returns](https://www.parliament.uk/business/publications/commons/Sessional-Returns/) page of the Parliament website lists statistics for previous sessions, including a breakdown of statutory instruments.

For example, in the [2016-17 session](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm201719/csession/1/108.htm#_idTextAnchor033), we can see that 166 affirmative instruments were presented to the House, alongside 537 negative instruments.

> is this procedure commonly used for law with a UK origin

Overwhelmingly, yes.